# Slider with left right navigation & numbers

Tags: jquery, navigation, numbers, gallery, photo

I want some jQuery slider with:

1. left side left navigation or an left arrow image
2. right side right navigation or an right arrow
3. List item
4. numbers 1, 2, 3, ... under the image...

Can anyone provide a link of that kind of gallery slider??

Answer (score 2):

I've used this one with great success:

http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 2):

Make one. It's probably 10-20 lines of code!

In short:

Position the images on top of each other using absolute positioning in CSS.
Add some controls using whatever HTML you want.
Bind events using jQuery to those elements.
Use either jQuery animate or CSS transitions to change the images on click.

Seriously, this is one of the simplest things to do and it's worth working out how to write it yourself.